# javascript - redux thunk doesn't wait for any promise

Tags: javascript, promise, redux, redux-thunk

I have an array like so

```
array =[ {message:'http://about.com'}, {message:'http://facebook.com'}]
```

I want to loop that array, at each item I will make request to server to fetch opengraph data then save the data back to array. This what I expect

```
array =[ 
    {
        message: { url:'http://about.com', title:'about'}
    }, 
    {
       message:{ url:'http://facebook.com', title:'facebook'}
    }
]
```

Then when it all finishes. I want to dispatch an action with payload is the expected array. Here is how I did it

```
return dispatch => {

    let array =[ {message:'http://about.com'}, {message:'http://facebook.com'}]

    let quests = array
    .map( (item) => {
        axios.get(getOpenGraphOfThisLink + item.message)
        .then( result =>{
            item.message = (result.data)
            return result
        })
    })

    Promise.all(quests).then( () => {
        console.log( 'modified', array)
        dispatch({
            type   : constant.GET_POST_COLLECTION_SUCCESS,
            payload: array
        })
        // this dispatch function sends my original array instead of modified one.
    })
}
```

The problem: the dispatch function in the code will send my original array to reducer instead of modified one. I want dispatch to send the new modified array. And I think it should it, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now `quests` variable is just assigned by your original array, because the `map` function return void, but you need to return promises of each item to the `quests`, so just add `return` key word, so that your code be like this:

```
let quests = array
    .map( (item) => {
        return axios.get(getOpenGraphOfThisLink + item.message)
        .then( result =>{
            item.message = (result.data)
            return result
        })
    })
```

Comment: Straightforwardly yes, but be aware of the proviso in my answer.

Comment: I got similar case,any idea how to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791724/javascript-redux-thunk-doesnt-wait-for-any-promise-again

Answer (score 0):

It's a scoping problem. You surely refer to a wrong variable:

```
return dispatch => {

    let array =[{ // <- the original array
      message:'http://about.com'
    }, {
      message:'http://facebook.com'
    }]

    let quests = array.map( (item) => {
        axios.get(getOpenGraphOfThisLink + item.message)
        .then( result =>{
            item.message = (result.data)
            return result
        })
    })

    Promise.all(quests).then(() => {
        console.log( 'modified', array) // <- here, array is reference to the original array
        dispatch({
            type   : constant.GET_POST_COLLECTION_SUCCESS,
            payload: array
        })
        // this dispatch function to send my original array instead of modified one.
    })
}
```

The function you pass to `Promise#then` should accept a single argument, result of resolution of the Promise. In case of `Promise.all`, this single argument is an array of results, every item referring to a Promise with corresponding index. So it should be

```
return dispatch => {

    let array =[{
      message:'http://about.com'
    }, {
      message:'http://facebook.com'
    }]

    let quests = array.map( (item) => {
        return axios.get(getOpenGraphOfThisLink + item.message) // don't forget to return when doing Array#map.
        .then( result =>{
            item.message = (result.data)
            return result
        })
    })

    Promise.all(quests).then((array) => { // <- the new array, redefined in scope of this arrow function
        console.log( 'modified', array) // <- here, array is reference to the new array which is the first argument of function passed to Promise#then.
        dispatch({
            type   : constant.GET_POST_COLLECTION_SUCCESS,
            payload: array
        })
        // this dispatch function will send the results of calling all the Promises passed to Promise.all!
    })
}
```

Comment: return axios work, but add the array param in then function will not work. so now my code just add 'return' keyword and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you are mutating `array.message` after each request has been completed with `result.data`.

IMO, you shouldn't do it

```
let quests = array.map((item) => {
    return axios.get(getOpenGraphOfThisLink + item.message)
                .then(result => result.data)
})

Promise.all(quests).then((values) => {
  // values contains all the result data.
}
```

Don't forget to handle error case.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not good practice to allow a function to mutate items passed to it.

In this case, if some axios.get()s succeeded and some failed, you would end up with a part-mutated array, which is, in all probability, undesirable.

Instead, you can map to an array of mutated *clones* of the original items, and deliver the mapped array down the promise chain.

Assuming no "getters" are involved, you can use `Object.assign()` to perform the cloning and mutation of clones.

```
let quests = array.map(item => {
    return axios.get(getOpenGraphOfThisLink + item.message)
    .then(result => Object.assign({}, item, { message: result.data });
});

return Promise.all(quests).then(arr => {
    console.log('mapped', arr); // note 'mapped', not 'mutated'
    // 'x'
    dispatch({
        'type': constant.GET_POST_COLLECTION_SUCCESS,
        'payload': arr
    });
});
```

Now, if you really wanted to mutate the original array, you can do so on an all-or-nothing basis at point 'x' with :

```
Object.assign(array, arr);
```

Comment: any idea about this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791724/javascript-redux-thunk-doesnt-wait-for-any-promise-again